# MariaDB on Windows - getting started help?

Tags: database, mariadb

I'm trying to learn MariaDB (v5.2.4), but I'm running into some issues.
I can download and install it, but it doesn't seem to be running or I'm missing something.

I'm looking for a good resource for the 1st timer running on Windows.

A few specific questions:

1. Does it require MySQL to run?  Alot of the installation help out there seems to be geared around upgrading from MySQL, but I want to start fresh.
2. Is there a management tool for the database (like SQL Server Management Studio)?  If not, what do people typically use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need MySQL to run MariaDB. Once you've installed MariaDB you should be able to type

```
net start mysql
```

at a command prompt and that will start MariaDB (yes you actually type mysql)

To answer the second part of your question, I know a company called Navicat used to offer an administrative gui, but I can't seem to find it on their site anymore.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  For some reason, when I navigate to the folder with mysql.exe in it, and I type 'net start mysql', it won't start with the error "the service name is invalid".  That error is what caused me to ask this question on SO.

Comment: yes i get the exact same issue! I've read that they fixed this on 5.2.3 but it is still happening for me on Windows 7 ultimate 32 bits

Comment: I'm having the issue on Windows 7 ultimate 64 bit.  Any answers anyone?  Should this be it's own question here on SO?

Comment: I opened a new question to try to solve my service name is invalid issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962342/mariadb-on-windows-what-is-this-error-when-trying-to-start-the-database-engine

Comment: This is my chosen best answer, with the caveat that you must view the other SO question in these notes if you encounter the issue I and lurscher encountered.

Answer (score 2):

If You need GUI server tool you can use Mysqlcc (it maybe work for MariaDB) or HeidiSQL (it is trully work for me) , go to google for get it...for HeidiSQL there is a portable version as I ussualy use it..but I use it in XP.....

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a post about how to install MariaDB. It's in spanish, because I haven't had time yet to translate to english.

http://www.manejandodatos.es/2013/9/probando-mariadb

For the second question, I use heidiSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog) as a GUI for MariaDB. The free version can be downloaded from here: https://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/wiki/Downloads . Also Navicat has a Mariadb Version which is paid.

As Google code has seen a shutdown,the latest version of SQLyog Community can be downloaded from here >> https://github.com/webyog/sqlyog-community/wiki/Downloads .