# MariaDB on Windows - what is this error when trying to start the database engine?

Tags: mariadb

I am asking this question as an offshoot myself and another SO had from this other MariaDB question:
[MariaDB on Windows - getting started help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940613/mariadb-on-windows-getting-started-help)

When I install MariaDB (v5.2.4), open the command window, navigate to the folder where the files are installed, and type in the following to start the database:

> net start mysql

I get the following error:

> the service name is invalid

I didn't do anything complex, just ran the installation and tried to get started.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error basically tells that installer did not create the service (it currently does not create services), thus you'll need to do it yourself.

- start elevated command line
- switch to directory of your MariaDB installation (C:\Program Files\MariaDB 5.2.4, something like that)
- bin\mysqld --install

and only then

- net start mysql

Assuming that there is nothing that runs on port 3306, this will stat.

Alas, the server you will create this way would not be optimized at all.
It is better to create a  configuration file my.ini (take a look at MySQL docs and .ini files in the installation directory for examples), and put with performance -related stuff here (innodb bufferpool size etc). With config file, you'll need a different command line to register service (step 3 above):

- bin\mysqld --install MySQL --defaults-file=path\to\my.ini

Installer for 5.2.4 is basic indeed. It is being reworked though,  new one is going to be better usable.

Comment: side remark: bin\mysqld --install only worked for me in cmd admin mode

Comment: of course, it installs service. And ,you should not use it mysqld --install anymore, in 2020

Comment: But what should I then do in 2020? In my case, I have simply installed mariadb. Normally, you can then simply open HeidiSQL and start with the default (localhost), someone told me. I do not get it to work. I do not know if starting the service and starting the server is needed, or if I miss something else.

Comment: you install database instance incl. service when you install MSI, as described here . https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-msi-packages-on-windows/ . If you chose the "Database Instance", MSI creates and starts the service, and MSI will fail and rollback the installation, if it can't start the service. If you want something more fancy, and you have ZIP and what not, you install with mysql_install_db.exe https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_install_dbexe/ .  It is there since 5.2.6, which is probably 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I installed MariaDB that comes with XAMPP on Windows 10. You will see only mysql in the XAMPP Control Panel. However, if you click Shell on the control panel you can access MariaDB monitor and MariaDB.
Here are some notes:
http://hodentekhelp.blogspot.com/2015/11/how-do-you-access-mariadb-in-xampp.html